# Install Ubuntu VirtualBox Bridged Network not recognized

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox

I'm trying to create a Ubuntu server virtual machine with Virtual Box command line, in a Ubuntu server 18.04. I followed the steps of [this site](https://devminz.github.io/posts/devops/virtualbox-cli-vm-bridged-networking/).
The bridged interface created:

```
vmubuntu01: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.15.201  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.15.255
        inet6 fe80::d4c2:1bff:fe4f:7524  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d6:c2:1b:4f:75:24  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1012  bytes 85102 (85.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

But when I'm installing virtual machine, it doesn't recognize the interface:

[image]

How do I get this bridge adapter "vmubuntu01" recognized at installation?
My intention is to set up this scenario:
[image]

Even setting the ip as static did not worked:
[image]
[image]

This image shows that ins’t connected to the network
[image]

Comment: What's the problem ? It has detected the interface . The interface name in the guest is not the same as the host's. In the host it's "vmubuntu01" , but it's en0s17 in the guest.

Comment: The problem is I can't get vm to assume vmubuntu01's ip (192.168.15.201).

Comment: How can I configure the vm network to assume this ip (bridged adapter)???

Comment: You can set a [static IP address](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-configure-a-static-ip-address-in-ubuntu-server-18-04/)

Comment: I tried setting static, the images are above

Answer (score 0):

[Netplan](https://netplan.io/reference)
`01-netcfg.yaml` change for your interface name,  address of your router and desired static IP.  In my case my ISP router is messing up DNS as well so I configure netplan to do DNS directly (do not use router)

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.200/24
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
        use-dns: false # https://netplan.io/reference don't use dhcp server (router) DNS
      dhcp6-overrides:
        use-dns: false
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8]
```

Install:

```
sudo ./01-netcfg.yaml /etc/netplan/.
sudo netplan apply
```